# Search Specific words in php array

Tags: php, pattern-matching

i have an array like this

```
$array = [
    'item1' => 'red', 
    'item2' => 'blue#foo#',
    'item3' => 'green',
    'item4' => 'white#foo2#',
    'item5' => 'bla#foo3#ck',
    'item6' => 'yellow#foo#'];
```

i wan't to get all word with surrounded by #word# like that (**word** can be **anything**)

```
$list = array_unique([ "#foo#", "#foo2#", "#foo3#", #foo#" ]);
```

and replace $list in $array with my data

```
$data = ['John', 'California', 'Cola', .......];
```

and go get finally

```
$array = [
    'item1' => 'red', 
    'item2' => 'blueJohn',
    'item3' => 'green',
    'item4' => 'whiteCalifornia',
    'item5' => 'blaColack',
    'item6' => 'yellowJohn'];
```

if someone can advice me.

**Edit** to @**mickmackusa**
   thanks for the link but, but how i can get my $list ?
and it's not really effeciancy because if my initial array have a lot of rows the loop can take some times, but thanks.

Is it the only way to do this with a loop ?

thanks in advance.

Comment: That's not very clear what do you want to replace those words with. Post your desired result of this array

Comment: I edited my publication, hoping that the problem was well explained and I am always listening if someone has a better idea than a loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you don't *have to* use a loop to perform replacements, but php is going to "iterate" the array no matter what syntax you use.

Regex provides a more concise code, but if you want better performance, `strtr()` inside of a loop will very likely perform faster.

I will declare your input data as `$array` in my snippets. Both examples to follow will provide this output:

```
array (
  'item1' => 'red',
  'item2' => 'blueJohn',
  'item3' => 'green',
  'item4' => 'whiteCalifornia',
  'item5' => 'blaColack',
  'item6' => 'yellowJohn',
)
```

Looped `strtr()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/IV4qG))

```
$translations = [
    '#foo#'  => 'John',
    '#foo2#' => 'California',
    '#foo3#' => 'Cola',
];

foreach ($array as &$item) {  // modify values by reference with & symbol
    $item = strtr($item, $translations);  // translate placeholder to desired substring from lookup array
}

var_export($array);
```

`preg_replace()`: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Et2D3))  *notice pattern delimiters are added to the lookup array

```
$translations = [
    '~#foo#~'  => 'John',
    '~#foo2#~' => 'California',
    '~#foo3#~' => 'Cola',
];

var_export(preg_replace(array_keys($translations), $translations, $array));
```

p.s. If you don't know how to generate your `$list`, then I can't fathom how you will be able to know how to translate particular placeholders into the appropriate value.  I am assuming you have enough project-logic knowledge to write an appropriate translation/lookup array.

Comment: thanks, for $list i probablly use regex to find #words# and build translations, it's can be anything because the initial array depends on which part of the project call the method and i want to globalize for all.